# Stringifyed onClick event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an event which parses a certain string which contains button name and URL.

than I assign the data to a button. and add on click event which suppose to open URL in a new window. But this on click event doe not work. The window does not show up. If URL was wrong it would open a window and prompt a mistake.

But in my case when I click the button it does not react. Probably something is wrong with on click event here: `onclick=\"myWindow = window.open('partArray[1]', '', 'width=300,height=300');\"` . But I can't understand what.

Here is the code:

```
 <script>
   ...
   var checkType = partArray[0].split("+");
   outPuts = outPuts + "  <input type='button' class='WordDocType' name='" + partArray[0] + "' value='" + partArray[0] + "' onclick=\"myWindow = window.open('partArray[1]', '', 'width=300,height=300');\" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;"
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=outPuts;
  </script>

   <body>
     ...
    <div id="demo"></div>
     ...
   </body>
```

Comment: why are you doing `myWindow = window.open` ?

Comment: because I want it to be opened in a new window

Comment: guess that is not needed. just `window.open` should be good enough.

Comment: Itried to create a button in htmal and assign same event to using html and it's working well

Comment: but it's working well if it's simple code. if I'm hardcoding it in html I mean. But if I populate a div through javascript it doesn't

Comment: I will try to remove myWindow. Wait a sec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`partArray[1]` is not evaluated; the browser should still open window with the URL specified as "partArray[1]" but I doubt that is what you want. Try adding double quotes and concatenating it when you build your HTML.

```
outPuts = outPuts + "  <input type='button' class='WordDocType' name='" + partArray[0] + "' value='" + partArray[0] + "' onclick=\"myWindow = window.open('" + partArray[1] + "', '', 'width=300,height=300');\" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;"
```

If you provide some more context or code it'd be easier to see what might be going on. Are you sure there is not a popup-blocker getting in the way?

Comment: yes when I tried to open it it gives me part[1' in the address line

Comment: Thank you Man. I didn't see that bug!!